# Error When Creating Custom Object in Google Drive Realtime API

Tags: javascript, object, google-drive-realtime-api

Ok, I am trying to create a collaborative custom object in Google Realtime API, following the Google Developers Guide https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model#registering_and_creating_custom_objects. However, it runs fine at the moment, however, when I try to create an object in the model (taking the two lines in the initializeModel function out of comments), I get the error "log:Net state changed from BUSY to CLIENT_ERROR". Not error is thrown up in the JavaScript. I don't know where I am going wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks,

```
        Project = function() {};
    registerTypes = function() {
        var custom = gapi.drive.realtime.custom;
        custom.registerType(Project, 'Project');                            
        Project.prototype.title = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('title');
        Project.prototype.date = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('date');
        Project.prototype.content = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('content');
}
/**
 * Set up the model - when creating a new file or loading an existing one.
 */

// the model for the messages in the chat
var messages = undefined;
// the name of the authenticated user - once authentication has succeeded
var username = "unkown";
var realtimeLoader = undefined;

/**
 * Set up the model - when creating a new file or loading an existing one.*/
var initializeModel = function(model) {
    var messages = model.createList();
    var dealines2 = model.createList();
    /*var project1 = model.create("Project");*/
    model.getRoot().set('messages', messages);
    /*model.getRoot().set('project1', project1);*/
    model.getRoot().set('dealines2', dealines2);
    console.log(model.getRoot());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever call registerTypes? Types need to be registered before a document is loaded.